# WPF animation doesn't show for one user and likely causing crash

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one user that doesn't see an animation during an async process and the other 6 users see the animation. When the process is done the application crashes for that one user. I think the crash is somehow related to the animation but there are no error messages.

When the process starts this code shows the animation

```
WorkingGears.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
displayGrid.IsEnabled = false;
headerGrid.IsEnabled = false;
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

var controller = ImageBehavior.GetAnimationController(WorkingGears);
controller.Play();

workerMainScrape.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The async process finishes and this code hides the animation

```
var controller = ImageBehavior.GetAnimationController(WorkingGears);
controller.Pause();

WorkingGears.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
displayGrid.IsEnabled = true;
headerGrid.IsEnabled = true;
```

What would cause one user to not see the animation and would it explain why the app crashes for them?

Comment: It's impossible for us to know what's going on without more info. Please see if you can wrap the problem code in a `try catch` block to get some kind of stack trace, and then post that in an update.

Comment: Could you be missing a codec on that machine?  Add a try/catch and see what exception you get.

Comment: That's a gif animation? Did the nuget dependencies or gif fail to install ? Is it a 32bit / 64 bit thing and the odd one out has a different one to the others? So they can't run say the 64bit dll you've installed.